# ORACLE XE Savepoints vs Snapshots

Tags: oracle

I am using a local instance of Oracle 11 XE to develop. For testing purposes I always need a clean database. Instead of always rebuilding a clean database I was thinking about using snapshots or savepoints to rollback to.

What are you guys using? Is there a better approach to quickly switch back to a specific database state?

Thanks & regards,
P.

Comment: Even cleaner is to deploy Oracle on a VM.  Take a snapshot, do your tests and revert to the snapshot.

Comment: Thanks. That is a good idea! Unfortunately we can not have a WM on our local machines (corporate policy...).

Comment: so get a copy of free esxi 6 and have infrastructure install it on a server.